# PyOpenSSL is it possible having the side with the private key connect to the one without?

Tags: python, ssl, pyopenssl

I want to have something like this:

```
def host():
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
    ctx.use_certificate_file(CERT_FILE)
    server = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM))
    server.bind(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    server.listen(1) 
    print "listening"
    conn,_ = server.accept()

def controller():
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
    ctx.use_privatekey_file(KEY_FILE)
    ctx.use_certificate_file(CERT_FILE)
    controller = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM))
    print "connecting"
    controller.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
```

However this results in an 'ssl handshake failure',
meanwhile this sort of behavior worked fine for me using the native ssl library while using this on the host side:`conn = ssl.wrap_socket(sock=conn, ca_certs=CERT_FILE, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)`

and this on the controller side:`ssl.wrap_socket(sock=conn, certfile=CERT_FILE, keyfile=KEY_FILE, server_side=True)`

So, is it possible to replicate this behavior using PyOpenSSL( can't just drop the module because I need the in-memory-certificate option )?

EDIT: Error traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-74:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-109-6bfd034a8592>", line 9, in host
    print conn.recv(1024)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1594, in recv
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1456, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_client_hello', 'no shared cipher')]
Exception in thread Thread-75:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-110-ec8e11869121>", line 10, in controller
    controller.sendall("yo")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1576, in sendall
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1456, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_write_bytes', 'ssl handshake failure')]
```

Comment: What are the errors exactly? Do you have the full traceback? also, `ca_certs=CERT_FILE` and `certfile=CERT_FILE` doesn't make sense to me, they should be different?

Comment: that combination is what did the trick :/ , also added error

Comment: ah i misread what you had there, got confused. I wonder what the output of `get_cipher_list()` is, basically I wonder if it might be necessary to pass along what cipher should be used? Or like maybe to be more explicit in the context something like : https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.Context.set_cipher_list ?

Comment: they both have the same cipher list and setting their cipher lists to a single common one didn't change a thing